# `AsyncExecutor` meant to execute one `AsyncTask` at a time sometimes executes two alongside each other

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

### `AsyncExecutor`

I have an [`AsyncExecutor`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/async/AsyncExecutor.html) that is defined as following:

```
asyncExecutor = new AsyncExecutor(1);
```

The constructor for the `AsyncExecutor` is `AsyncExecutor(int maxConcurrent)`, whereas the `maxConcurrent` is how many `AsyncTask`s is allowed to run alongside each other at one point in time. If it’s set to one, it’s then supposed to run all `AsyncTask`s contained by it in the order they were added.

### `AsyncTask`

I’m implementing the `AsyncTask` interface on a class I’ve created to handle a certain set of logic that needs be run one by one in the order they’re `submit`ted onto the `AsyncExecutor`—by calling the `submit` method on the `AsyncExecutor`:

```
private class Foo implements AsyncTask<Object>
{
    // ...

    public Foo()
    {
        // Transfers variables over
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Start");

        // Does some stuff here

        System.out.println("Stop");

        return null;
    }
}
```

I then `submit` these `Foo`s onto the `asyncExecutor` every once in a while and require them to run in order from the time they were added. This is the case most of the time, but let’s have a look at the console output—every once in a while, this isn’t the case:

> `...`
>   `Start`
>   `Stop`
>   `Start`
>   `Stop`
>   `Start`
>   `Start`
>   `Stop`
>   `Start`
>   `Start`
>   `Stop`

Is there something I’ve missed? This is clearly supposed to never have “Start” stated on two lines next to one another—nor “Stop” for that matter.

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: well, it's rather difficult to reproduce without knowing how exactly you submit tasks to executor. And it's kinda strange to use Async with only one task at a time since you want them to be executed one by one not in parallel. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @Enigo I one task at a time to run alongside the renderer thread of *LibGDX*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have an uncaught Exception in the *AsyncTask* implementation. Because there is no exception barrier in your `AsyncTask.call` implementation the thread will just die trying. That is why you have multiple occurrences for **Start**, but not for **Stop**.

You may add some parameters as indication to your `System.out.println()` to get an idea if this is happening at all.

As a solution, just add some try-catch for **Throwable** with a print line to your *Foo* class.

The example that I used for testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    AsyncExecutor asyncExecutor = new AsyncExecutor(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        asyncExecutor.submit(new Foo(i));
    }
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}

static class Foo implements AsyncTask<Object>
{

    private int i;

    public Foo(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception
    {
        try{
            System.out.println("Start" + i + "/" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            if((this.i % 9) == 0){
                throw new Exception("Ugly.");
            }

            System.out.println("Stop " + i + "/" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        } catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wondeful notice! I’ll look into it and see if it solves all my problems—pretty sure it will now that you bring this up!